# yescrypt crypting sha512

Tags: 22.04

i'm use to setup Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on Azure where SHA512 is used to encrypt password.
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-1050-azure
Architecture: x86-64

Now, one of my client setup is own Ubuntu 'ON_PREMISE' server with Ubuntu 22.04LTS and the encryption methode is 'yescrypt'

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-87-generic
Architecture: x86-64

The utility file about password is setup to use DES and SHA512.

Before asking programmers to adapt the program, I wonder if this will end up being the default in Azure images too.

Or what if I proceed to change the encryption from 'yescrypt' to 'sha512' in the Linux configuration files?

What do you think?

I found that /etc/pam.d/common-password should be modified as follows: password [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure sha512